# How do rotate x-axis labels to left or negative in c3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

How do you rotate x-axis labels to left or negative using c3js.org?  [This example](http://c3js.org/samples/axes_x_tick_rotate.html) gives the following code:

```
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'category',
        tick: {
            rotate: 75,
            multiline: false
        },
        height: 130
    }
}
```

But if I try "**rotate: -65,**" instead like [this d3js.org example](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/3c040800ff6457717cca586ae9547dbf), the x-axis labels disappear from the plot.  I am using "type: 'timeseries',", but I don't think that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Should have tried this before posting, but thought I would share...this works:

```
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'category',
        tick: {
            rotate: -20,
            multiline: false
        },
        height: 35
    }
}
```

It is a combination of rotation and height (doh).